# Наложение изображения на изображение

Tags: android

Есть два файла с изображениями, первое - карта местности, второе - знак указателя. В зависимости от неких входящих данных, я должен наложить изображение указателя на изображение карты с точными координатами относительно изображения карты. То есть в итоге я должен получит скрещенное изображение в каком либо виде, либо в виде файла, например png, либо в виде объекта, `ImageView` например. Главное чтобы его можно было вывести.

Каким образом можно это осуществить?

Comment: Может быть попробовать использовать FrameLayout, внутри положить 2 ImageView? Верхний - это ваша стрелка, позиционировать которую можно попробовать с помощью margins в LayoutParams (правда, не уверен, что это будет работать, сам не пробовал). Второй вариант использовать RelativeLayout и также позиционировать стрелку через LayoutParams.